# Appengine: TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Tring to assign a value via constructor. but getting "TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment".

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class test(ndb.Model):
    status = ndb.StringProperty(default=None)

    def __init__(self):
         self.status = "Test Status"


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     def get(self):
          a = test()
          a.put()           


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

Error:

```
  File "/home/user/Appengine/guestbook/guestbook.py", line 15, in get
    a = test()
  File "/home/user/Appengine/guestbook/guestbook.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.status = "Test Status"
  File "/home/user/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1265, in __set__
    self._set_value(entity, value)
  File "/home/user/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1011, in _set_value
    self._store_value(entity, value)
  File "/home/user/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 992, in _store_value
    entity._values[self._name] = value
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but perhaps you should call `ndb.Model.__init__(self)` first.  (or you could probably use `super`)...  That might set `entity._values` to something other than `None`...

Comment: @mgilson ```ndb.Model.__init__(self)``` taht works. Btb how can i add a key_name for the above code ?

Comment: key_name?  What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean entity id like this ```a = test(id='unique_id')```. And retive that entity by ```test.get_by_id('unique_id')```

Comment: Ahh ... That looks right to me.  Did you try it?

Comment: On the whole you should avoid overriding __init__, if you do some searching through SO you will find people having a number of issues with using __init__ due to the way metacalsses are used.  If you really want this sort of functionality you should consider using a factory (classmethod to instantiate and do other stuff)

Comment: Also this __init__ method is completely redundant as you can set the default value of the property using default="Test Status"

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to initialize the `ndb.Model` properly by calling its `__init__`:

```
class test(ndb.Model):
    status = ndb.StringProperty(default=None)

    def __init__(self):
        ndb.Model.__init__(self)
        self.status = "Test Status"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass over any arguments, you'd need to do

```
class Test(ndb.Model): # Classes have uppercase first letter...
    status = ndb.StringProperty(default=None)

    def __init__(self, *a, **k):
        super(Test, self).__init__(self)
        self.status = "Test Status"
```

Then you should be able to do

```
a = Test(foo='bar')
```

I'm not sure about the `status` thing, however.